# How to setup Flot for iOS retina display

Tags: ios, ipad, flot, retina-display

I have tested this on an iPad (3 generation). The line chart appears perfectly smooth.

http://justindarc.github.com/flot.touch/example/index.html

I have tried diffing the code with my flot code and cannot see any significant difference that would cause it to run in retina mode. My flot is version 0.7, same as his code. No matter what I try my own chart runs in non-retina mode.

**What is the trick in running retina mode?**

My setup code is rather long.

```
function setup_chart0(setup_options) {
    var point_data = [];
    if(setup_options.use_sample_data_for_chart0) {
        point_data = generate_dummy_data(
            setup_options.timestamp_generate_min,
            setup_options.timestamp_generate_max
        );
    }
    var average_data = henderson23(point_data);
    var datasets = make_chart0_datasets(point_data, average_data);

    if(is_dualaxis_detail_mode) {
        datasets = make_chart0_dual_datasets(
            [], 
            [],
            [], 
            []
        );
    }


    var options = default_plot_options();
    options.xaxis.min = setup_options.timestamp_visible_min;
    options.xaxis.max = setup_options.timestamp_visible_max;
    options.xaxis.panRange = [setup_options.timestamp_pan_min, setup_options.timestamp_pan_max];
    options.yaxis.min = -0.025;
    options.yaxis.max = 1.025;
    options.yaxis.panRange = [-0.025, 1.025];
    options.legend = { container: '#legend0', noColumns: 2 };
    options.grid.markings = compute_markings_with_alertlevels;

    if(is_dualaxis_detail_mode) {
        options.y2axis = {};
        options.y2axis.position = "right";
        options.y2axis.min = -0.025;
        options.y2axis.max = 1.025;
        options.y2axis.panRange = [-0.025, 1.025];
        options.legend = { container: '#legend_hidden', noColumns: 2 };
    }

    //save_as_file({ samples: point_data, average: average_data });

    var el_placeholder0 = $("#placeholder0");
    if(el_placeholder0.length){
        //console.log('plotting chart 0');
        var fade = false;
        var el = el_placeholder0;
        var el_outer = $("#placeholder0_outer");
        var original_offset = el_outer.offset();
        if(fade) {
            el_outer.offset({ top: -5000, left: 0 });  // move plot container off screen 
        }
        chart0 = $.plot(el, datasets, options);
        if(fade) {
            el.hide();  // hide plot - must do *after* creation 
            el_outer.offset(original_offset); // put plot back where it belongs 
            el.fadeIn('slow'); // fade in
        }

        /*var s = '   width: ' + chart0.width() + ' height: ' + chart0.height();
        $('#label0').append(s);*/

        if(solo_pan_mode) {
            el.bind('plotpan', function (event, plot) {
                set_data_should_redraw_chart0 = true;
                set_data_should_redraw_chart1 = false;
                set_data_should_redraw_chart2 = false;
                fetch_data_for_chart(chart0, setup_options.timestamp);
                show_loading_empty('#loader1');
                show_loading_empty('#loader2');
            }); 
            el.bind('plotpanend', function (event, plot) {
                set_data_should_redraw_chart0 = true;
                set_data_should_redraw_chart1 = true;
                set_data_should_redraw_chart2 = true;
                copy_min_max(chart0, chart1, '#placeholder1');
                copy_min_max(chart0, chart2, '#placeholder2');
                hack_hide_loading_wheels = true;
                maybe_hide_loading_wheels();
            }); 
        } else {
            el.bind('plotpan', function (event, plot) {
                fetch_data_for_chart(chart0, setup_options.timestamp);
                sync_with_chart0();
            }); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified jquery.flot.js like this:

In the top I have added

```
retinaMode = (window.devicePixelRatio > 1),
```

I have extended these functions

```
function makeCanvas(skipPositioning, cls) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.className = cls;
    c.width = canvasWidth;
    c.height = canvasHeight;

    if (!skipPositioning)
        $(c).css({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 });

    $(c).appendTo(placeholder);

    if(retinaMode) {
        c.width = canvasWidth * 2;
        c.height = canvasHeight * 2;
        c.style.width = '' + canvasWidth + 'px';
        c.style.height = '' + canvasHeight + 'px';
    }

    if (!c.getContext) // excanvas hack
        c = window.G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(c);

    // used for resetting in case we get replotted
    c.getContext("2d").save();

    if (retinaMode) {
         c.getContext("2d").scale(2,2);
    }

    return c;
}

function getCanvasDimensions() {
    canvasWidth = placeholder.width();
    canvasHeight = placeholder.height();

    if (canvasWidth <= 0 || canvasHeight <= 0)
        throw "Invalid dimensions for plot, width = " + canvasWidth + ", height = " + canvasHeight;
}

function resizeCanvas(c) {
    // resizing should reset the state (excanvas seems to be
    // buggy though)
    if (c.width != canvasWidth) {
        c.width = canvasWidth;
        if(retinaMode) {
            c.width = canvasWidth * 2;
        }
        c.style.width = '' + canvasWidth + 'px';

    }

    if (c.height != canvasHeight) {
        c.height = canvasHeight;
        if(retinaMode) {
            c.height = canvasHeight * 2;
        }
        c.style.height = '' + canvasHeight + 'px';
    }

    // so try to get back to the initial state (even if it's
    // gone now, this should be safe according to the spec)
    var cctx = c.getContext("2d");
    cctx.restore();

    // and save again
    cctx.save();

    if(retinaMode) {
        cctx.scale(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: With retina now available on OSX, you need to handle another case. Safari on OSX will auto-double the dimensions of the canvas backing store if the devicePixelRatio is 2. iOS safari doesn't do that, because of memory and viewport scaling issues. So now you need to check if context.backingStorePixelRatio is 1 before you double.

Comment: I should add, this is only in the Safari 6 beta at the moment. And that property should be context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio

Comment: I tested your answer with 0.7 and the simulator in retina mode and I get a chart that takes up a quarter of the area that it should. This is on iOS 5.1. This is because the drawing logic still thinks the canvas is 400x300, even though we doubled it to 800x600.

Comment: For what it worths, I submitted a pull request to the flot core that add support for retina display (including the new MacBook Pro) : https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/52

Comment: @olivier that looks great. Nice patch you got there. Thank you.